# When my C# form crashes it tries to create a new instance of itself

Tags: c#, arrays, forms

I do some rather long winded things with a forms application using arrays and sometimes I address it wrongly during development, instead of an obvious error or a crash the whole application restarts and tries to run:

```
Application.Run(new SplashForm());
```

Why does this happen? It makes debugging very painful!

Thanks

Comment: post some more code! is the Application.Run command in a (try)catch clausule?

Comment: I don't understand what you want from this type of details, please ask point to point questions mentioning proper details.

Comment: I can't work out what code to post - if at any point anything fails (for example if i try to address an array value which doesnt exist) it will try to run the forms application again! 
I'm not sure how to isolate which bit is causing the issue and wondered if there was any stupid obvious things to check! 
The application.run is basically on its own in main() so that isn't the problem.

Comment: You create the splash form in Application.Run... Where does the main form get created?

Comment: Then post any code in the splashform constructor ?

Comment: Don't bother posting production code - just post a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem. Something we can copy, paste, compile, run, and see the issue.

Comment: The forms after the splash form are created in the "next form buttons" as the previous forms are hidden. But this is probably not the ideal method.
E.g.

    welcomeForm welcome = new welcomeForm();
    welcome.show();
    this.hide();

and then chaining them together, back boxes do the same for the previous form. (My application is an installer and so has very linear user interaction)

Comment: Ok it seems to be something about returning from a background worker that is trying to call the main function again instead of nicely returning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to invoke the UI thread on a non existing control. It's probably throwing Cross-Thread exception, and because you do not have error handling, it's crashing at the return point of the new SplashForm()

When you run the application in debug mode, check your "output" window to see if any exception messages show up.
You could possibly see a message like "cross-thread operation not valid accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Answer (score 3):

You might want to add error handling to your Application. Here's some code we use for that: -

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    static class Program
    {

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
            Application.ThreadException += new System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            HandleException(e.Exception);
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            HandleException((Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
        }

        static void HandleException(Exception e)
        {
        //Handle it here
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks,

Phil.
http://exceptioneer.com

Comment: Thanks Phil, that looks great and I have added it but any errors still cause it to crash badly rather than trigger an exception, Is there a generic coverall I should add here?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project has an application level error handler that everything is bubbling up to.

You may want to put error handling code in the appropriate places in the application.

Comment: I have error handling code already, but when it is trigged it causes the application.run() anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks for all your help but i worked it out, the problem was it was returning to the RunWorkerCompletedEvent from the background worker it was setting a label property, this works fine except that the label is named differently to the label text being set, and since im getting the control programatically and then setting the value it is hard to diagnose.

Strange behaviour though, if the control does not exist it reload the entire form, can anyone explain this?

Thanks again everyone